# PowerBI - Databricks Connection using Service Principal

Tags: powerbi, azure-storage, azure-databricks, powerbi-datasource

How do we set up a connection between Databricks and PowerBI (Microsoft Fabric) using a Service Principal that has a Databricks PAT? We tried doing this in the online PowerBI UI, and don't know how to configure the data source credentials using the PAT. Is the data source and authentication method set up in PowerBI desktop instead?

Answer (score 0):

As per Connect [Power BI to Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/partners/bi/power-bi) you must use Power BI Desktop 2.98.683.0 or above (October 2021 release).
To use access tokens belonging to service principals

***Note: As a security best practice when you authenticate with personal access tokens, Databricks recommends that you use personal access tokens belonging to service principals instead of workspace users.***

To create tokens for service principals, Know more about [Manage tokens for a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals#--manage-tokens-for-a-service-principal).

You can refer through [Connect Power BI Desktop to Azure Databricks manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/partners/bi/power-bi#--connect-power-bi-desktop-to-azure-databricks-manually)

Also Know about [Provision a service principal for Azure Databricks automation - Azure Databricks UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/service-principals#next-steps)